# find: list date and size without using -printf

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find

Is there a way to do the following without using the -printf option, which I don't have?

```
find . -printf "%p (%s, %Tb %Td %TY %TH:%TM)\n"
```

Basically I want the size and date/time to be listed alongside the names.

A sample output of the following structure:

```
 .
 |-one
 |-two
 | |-two_2
 | |-two_1
 |-test_file
```

would be:

```
. (4096, Mar 06 2019 16:38)
./one (4096, Mar 06 2019 16:37)
./two (4096, Mar 06 2019 16:38)
./two/two_2 (4096, Mar 06 2019 16:38)
./two/two_1 (4096, Mar 06 2019 16:38)
./test_file (0, Mar 06 2019 16:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

```
-exec stat
```

could be used instead to get size and date info.

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%n  (%z , %A , %s)' {} + | sed -
e s'/.000000000//'g
```

This is useful when the -printf option is not available.